# Who is My Fellow?

Tags: halacha, lashon-hara-slander

In the Kitzur Shulchan Aruch, in the siman on Lishon Hara (30), the Kitzur references the role of "fellow" several times. Who counts as fellow here? Is it only fellow Jews or anyone?

Comment: Perhaps @YochananMichael the answer may be connected to who is considered to be "your neighbor?"

Comment: @JJLL, that is essentially the question.

Comment: It might be helpful if you quoted the relevant passages, or some of them. (For example, does he say you can't relay _lashon hara_ about your fellow? can't relay it to your fellow? can't listen to your fellow tell it? Or is perhaps "fellow" a term used in a specific case, e.g. someone you're very comfortable with and need to be extra-vigilant about not telling _lh"r_ to, or someone you can trust not to relay it further?)

Answer (score 1):

As the Chofetz Chaim points out right away, it is specifically חברך במצוות, your fellow keeper of the mitzvos (at the least, shabbos in public), who is included in the mitzva of lashon hara.